# Why memset works to initialize 2D array in C++ with zero but failed to set when declared like this `array[n][k+1]={0}`?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, memset, variable-length-array

I have initialized an array like this `array[n][k+1]={0}` where n and k are user input. But I found that it doesn't initialize all index values to zero. While on the other hand `memset(array,0,sizeof(array))` works fine. So why this happened?

Because each time I initialised like this `array[n][n]={0}`, it always works fine. But why not in this case.

Comment: "`array[n][k+1]={0}` where n and k are user input." is not valid c++.

Comment: Unless `n` and `k` are compile time constants, `array[n][k+1]` is not legal C++ and any result you get is what you get.

Comment: *"n and k are user input"*.  VLA is not valid C++. it is an extension.

Comment: Related to the VLA: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: Why you don't get the expected initialization comes down to compiler implementers and how they decide to deal with a non-standard extension. I suspect it's because this is the behaviour required by C99.

Comment: Looked it up. I'm wrong. C99 flat-out rejects initialization, so this is the C++ compiler implementers just doing whatever they felt like. I really need to update my copy of K&R.

Comment: And yet another person is taken in by the fool's gold of variable-length-arrays.  @OP -- Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> myarray(n, std::vector<int>(k+1));` -- Not only is that going to work because it is standard, it sets the array to all `0`.